# pipelinedb unrecognized node type: 5009

Tags: pipelinedb

I have a problem creating Continuous Transform from any client but psql.

Reproduce:

1. OS: OSX EL Capitan 10.11.6
2. Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
3. `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 pipelinedb/pipelinedb`

Now, I connect to DB via PHPStorm 2017.2, it is OK.

I create some streams with query:

`CREATE STREAM some_stream (id INT, amount INT)`.

It is also OK.

Then I try to create CONTINUOUS TRANSFORM with query:

`CREATE CONTINUOUS TRANSFORM my_transform AS SELECT id, amount FROM some_stream`

And there I get an error: "**unrecognized node type: 5009**".

But! I tried this query with psql:

`psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d pipeline -Upipeline -c "CREATE CONTINUOUS TRANSFORM my_transform AS SELECT id, amount FROM some_stream"`

And it works! No error! That's the problem.

I tried to execute this query via php-doctrine-migration, via php-adminer, and there I have the same error.

Does anybody know, what is it? Why it works only with psql?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the `0.9.8` version? e.g.,

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 pipelinedb/pipelinedb:0.9.8
```

Comment: Done. I've tried to run image with:
`docker run -d -p 5432:5432 pipelinedb/pipelinedb:0.9.8`

And now I have this error:
`unrecognized node type: 960`

Comment: I think the issue is with the client you're using. It seems like it's receiving a parse tree from the server but doesn't know how to handle PipelineDB's node types.

Comment: I use only PHPStorm, php-doctrine-migration, php-adminer. They all applicable to work with PostgresQL DB. I sow in documentation to PipelineDB, that it works fine with any PostgresQL client. So, isn't it true? I'm totally stuck in this problem. I just can't use pipelineDB, but I really want :(
Could anyone reproduce the problem? Or it is only on my OS?

Comment: PipelineDB works with any PostgreSQL client at the wire protocol level. But the client you're using seems to be making assumptions about things at a higher level than that. It appears that it's parsing actual query trees itself, which is usually only done on the server for this exact reason. I would recommend just using a different or more standard client.